# Intermittent Service not available Error in Elasticbeanstalk application

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

We are using a webserver with ElasticBeanstalk from 2019.,

the platform is

tomcat 8.5 with java8 running on 64 bit Amazon Linux. httpd as proxy

recently (from Jan 30th) we started getting Service Unavailable issues if go to the endpoint from time to time. and if we refresh 2-3 times it will get resolved on its own.

then I download full logs. under elasticbeanstalk-error_log I can see

```
[Mon Feb 28 10:00:58.338035 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757313533696] (13)Permission denied: AH02454: HTTP: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/ (localhost) failed
[Mon Feb 28 10:00:58.338078 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757313533696] [client <private-ip-here>:12566] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: http://<custom-end-point>/1/<name.jsp>?s=sec$$4P!&refresh=300
[Mon Feb 28 10:43:40.663468 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757120071424] (13)Permission denied: AH02454: HTTP: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/ (localhost) failed
[Mon Feb 28 10:43:40.663518 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757120071424] [client <private-ip-here>:21136] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

repeated multiple times from Jan30th.

and when I look at **access.log**

***I can see 503 error log exactly at the same time when permission denied error logs in elasticbeanstalk-error_log***

And I looked at the running process using ps -aux | grep HTTPd and ps -aux | grep tomcat

both are running from 2019 and have no restarts.

what more I can do to troubleshoot these issuesWe are running a web application written in Java(tomcat8) hosted in AWS ElastcBeanStalk

Some weeks back we started getting 503 error randomly

When we checked the elasticbeanstalk-erorr_logs
[Thu Mar 03 13:22:12.906144 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757338711808] (13)Permission denied: AH02454: HTTP: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/httpd/ (localhost) failed
[Thu Mar 03 13:22:12.906202 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 14882:tid 139757338711808] [client 172.31.17.0:61382] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: http://our-domain.com/1/callBackLog.jsp

The error logs are suggesting connection error with backend unix socket
When we checked in /var/run/httpd/ folder, there were no unix sockets(.sock files)

But in apache httpd config
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Proxy *>
Require all granted

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost on

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

the proxy backend is ip address not unix socket

As per the config httpd should connect to backend ip address(localhost:8080) but why is it complaining about unix socket

Have anyone faced similar issues?

=============    UPDATE

The error logs are suggesting connection error with backend unix socket

When we checked in /var/run/httpd/ folder, there were no unix sockets(.sock files)

But in apache httpd config

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Proxy *>
Require all granted

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPreserveHost on

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

the proxy backend is ip address not unix socket

As per the config httpd should connect to backend ip address(localhost:8080) but why is it complaining about unix socket

Have anyone faced similar issues?

Comment: I'm seeing the same intermittent issue lately on a server that's also been running for years. My setup is the same as yours (tomcat 8.5, Java 8, httpd, Amazon Linux 1). Checking the logs, errors also started showing up for me on exactly Jan 30 of this year. Did you find out what was causing this to happen on your server?